# How to disable inplace renaming in Resharper?

Tags: resharper

How to disable inplace renaming in Resharper? 
I find inplace editing very uncomfortable, compared to editing in Rename dialog.

Comment: To clarify the question. When I press F2 (rename refactoring), I want it to open 'Rename' dialog to edit identifier. Currently it performs editing right in code window. I guess it works that way only for local variables, as it does open 'Rename' dialog for class members. What I want is that it open the dialog _always_ - including for local variables.

Answer (score 2):

Are you talking about the in-place refactoring? If so, go to the Resharper Options menu and under the Code Editing tab click on Context Actions. Then just uncheck the box with the label "Apply in-place refactoring."

Hope this helps.

Comment: There are two items with such name. I unchecked both for all settings layers, but I don’t see any changes. Still no dialog window for renaming when I press F2 on local variable.

Comment: There is no way to disable in-place refactoring. Mentioned settings adjusts an availability of "Apply rename refactoring" context action in Alt+Enter menu, when you e.g. change the name of any local variable directly in the code (without pressing F2 shortcut) and would like to apply such renaming to all usages of the variable.